# Can't find Build Action in ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, vs-web-site-project

I have the following [problem](http://forums.asp.net/t/1567054.aspx), but I can't reproduce the solution because I can't find Build Action property in my resource  properties.

Why? Where is that?

Comment: in the properties panel when you click the file

Comment: I have only: File Name and Full Path. Nothing more

Comment: Those 2 appear in the misc group. In the advanced group you should see Build action, copy to output directory, custom tool, custom tool name.

Comment: I have the Misc group only. Why?

Comment: @user2441297 select the file and do this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IunEp.png

Comment: The problem is - I HAVE the Misc group ONLY: http://i.imgur.com/RtzBKxs.png

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET web sites do not build.

This is one of the best reasons not to use web sites. Most examples will assume web applications. Use web application projects instead of web sites.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476(v=vs.100).aspx